# Excel Reading Specific Data and Write to notepad in Specific Format

Tags: excel

At my job I have to manually input a lot of data in a specific format on .txt file. I gather that data from a specific excel file. I manually select the number I want from a column and copy it to the txt file.

Sometimes I have to do 100's of rows at a time, which is rather time-consuming. If I had access to Matlab I'd be able to write a script that does this for me in a matter of minutes, but my company doesnt have access to it. I only have Excel access.

So I'm looking into writing some sort of Macro to do this intensive work for me. But not sure how to start, not very experienced on this.

This is the data I have on Excel format:

[Excel Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKO7F.png)

As you can see, it's a defined format every time. Columns range from A to N. But I only need Data from Column H I and O. I need every row present though.

The data needed I circled around with green. But basically:

Column H: ItemKindIndex[**44557**(

So I would look for the first marker where I should start reading my number, which is after '[' and ends on the '('

Column I: Option[**268440733**[

Data of Interest is between '[' and '['

Column O: ItemPeriod[**0**]

Data of Interest is between '[' and ']'

In this case, I need the following numbers: 44557   ,   268440733   , 0

Then I would like to have them written in the following format to a .txt file:

```
<itemServerData itemKind="44557" itemOption="268440733" itemPeriod="0" />
```

I would have as many lines like this one above as many rows I have on my excel file.

I appreciate everyone's help that can chime in!

Thank you guys,

Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below formula in any of the empty columns and drag it till the end of the list,

```
="<itemServerData itemKind="""&(MID(A1,(FIND("[",A1,1)+1),(FIND("(",A1,1))-FIND("[",A1,1)-1))&""" itemOption="""&(MID(B1,(FIND("[",B1,1)+1),(FIND("[",B1,(FIND("[",B1,1)+1)))-FIND("[",B1,1)-1))&""" itemPeriod="""&(MID(C1,(FIND("[",C1,1)+1),(FIND("]",C1,1))-FIND("[",C1,1)-1))&""""&" />"
```

Please replace A1 with column H, B1 with column I and C1 with column O. This would give you the exact string which you can use it. Let me know if you face any difficulties.